# Multi-Loops for Converting Data Layout

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I'm not very experienced with loops, but this is how far I got. I'm trying to convert data I get into an aesthetically pleasing format. I have the basic loop which can pull info into some form of structure, but it misses some of the data because I cannot write the loop properly.

My data is imported as multiple flows which have a start (ZHV) and an end (ZPT) row, and contain multiple records, each records may contain multiple parts. Ideally I want each individual record, with it's constituent parts, on one row, and that's what I'm trying to convert to.

Below is an example table of data:

```
ZHV 1001                                
58C A   B   C   D                   
59C E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M
60C N   O   P   Q   R   S           
ZPT 20151002                                
ZHV 1002                                
58C A   B   C   D                   
59C E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M
60C N   O   P   Q   R   S           
ZPT 20151003                                
ZHV 1003                                
58C A   B   C   D                   
59C E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M
60C N   O   P   Q   R   S           
ZPT 20151004                                
ZHV 1004                                
58C A   B   C   D                   
59C E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M
60C N   O   P   Q   R   S           
60C N   O   P   Q   R   S           
58C A   B   C   D                   
59C E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M
60C N   O   P   Q   R   S           
60C N   O   P   Q   R   S           
58C A   B   C   D                   
59C E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M
60C N   O   P   Q   R   S           
60C N   O   P   Q   R   S           
ZPT 20151005
```

Each flow can have multiple records ()58C and each record can have multiple parts (59C and 60C).

Hopefully after conversion the data should look like this:

```
ZHV 1001    58C A   B   C   D   59C E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   60C N   O   P   Q   R   S                           
ZHV 1002    58C A   B   C   D   59C E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   60C N   O   P   Q   R   S                           
ZHV 1003    58C A   B   C   D   59C E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   60C N   O   P   Q   R   S                           
ZHV 1004    58C A   B   C   D   59C E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   60C N   O   P   Q   R   S   60C N   O   P   Q   R   S
            58C A   B   C   D   59C E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   60C N   O   P   Q   R   S   60C N   O   P   Q   R   S
            58C A   B   C   D   59C E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   60C N   O   P   Q   R   S   60C N   O   P   Q   R   S
ZHV 1004    58C A   B   C   D   59C E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   60C N   O   P   Q   R   S
```

Here is the code i'm currently using but it only pulls the first 58C, 59C and 60C it find for each Flow (ZHV).

Can you anyone suggest how to modify it to add in the extra fields per record per flow?

```
Public Sub Shift()

Dim Master As Worksheet
Dim Slave As Worksheet

Set Master = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set Slave = Worksheets("Sheet1")


For j = 2 To 2000 'Master

For i = 2 To 2000 'Slave

    If Trim(Slave.Cells(j, 3).Value2) = vbNullString Then Exit For
    If Slave.Cells(i, 1) = "ZHV" Then
        k = i + 1
        l = k + 1
        m = l + 1
            Master.Cells(j, 2).Value2 = Slave.Cells(i, "B").Value2
            Master.Cells(j, 3).Value2 = Slave.Cells(i, "C").Value2
            Master.Cells(j, 4).Value2 = Slave.Cells(i, "D").Value2
            Master.Cells(j, 5).Value2 = Slave.Cells(i, "E").Value2
            Master.Cells(j, 6).Value2 = Slave.Cells(i, "F").Value2
            Master.Cells(j, 7).Value2 = Slave.Cells(i, "G").Value2
            Master.Cells(j, 8).Value2 = Slave.Cells(i, "H").Value2
            Master.Cells(j, 9).Value2 = Slave.Cells(i, "L").Value2

            If Slave.Cells(k, 1) = "58C" Then
                Master.Cells(j, 12).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 2).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 13).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 3).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 14).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 4).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 15).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 5).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 16).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 6).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 17).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 7).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 18).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 8).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 19).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 9).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 20).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 10).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 21).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 11).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 22).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 12).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 23).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 13).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 24).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 14).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 25).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 15).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 26).Value2 = Slave.Cells(k, 16).Value2
            End If

            If Slave.Cells(l, 1) = "59C" Then
                Master.Cells(j, 27).Value2 = Slave.Cells(l, 2).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 28).Value2 = Slave.Cells(l, 3).Value2

            End If

            If Slave.Cells(m, 1) = "60C" Then
                Master.Cells(j, 29).Value2 = Slave.Cells(m, 2).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 30).Value2 = Slave.Cells(m, 3).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 31).Value2 = Slave.Cells(m, 4).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 32).Value2 = Slave.Cells(m, 5).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 33).Value2 = Slave.Cells(m, 6).Value2
                Master.Cells(j, 34).Value2 = Slave.Cells(m, 7).Value2

            End If

            i = i + 1
            j = j + 1
    End If
Next
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: This is a bit hard to follow. Can you include an example of the "aesthetically pleasing format" you wish to achieve?

Comment: Hi @MatthewD . Please see amended post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to loop through the data and output it based on the value in columnA.

Try something like this.

```
Private Sub Shift()

    Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lSourceRow As Long
    Dim lTargetRow As Long
    Dim lOffset As Long

    'Define the source and target sheets
    Set wsSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    lSourceRow = 1
    lTargetRow = 0

    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    wsSource.Activate
    'Loop through the rows
    Do While lSourceRow <= lastRow

        'Check if we have the beginning of a flow
        If wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value = "ZHV" Then

            wsTarget.Range("A" & lTargetRow + 1).Value = wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value
            wsTarget.Range("B" & lTargetRow + 1).Value = wsSource.Range("B" & lSourceRow).Value

        End If

        If wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value = "58C" Then

            lTargetRow = lTargetRow + 1

            wsTarget.Range("C" & lTargetRow).Value = wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value
            wsTarget.Range("D" & lTargetRow).Value = wsSource.Range("B" & lSourceRow).Value
            wsTarget.Range("E" & lTargetRow).Value = wsSource.Range("C" & lSourceRow).Value
            wsTarget.Range("F" & lTargetRow).Value = wsSource.Range("D" & lSourceRow).Value
            wsTarget.Range("G" & lTargetRow).Value = wsSource.Range("E" & lSourceRow).Value

        ElseIf wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value = "59C" Then

            lOffset = 0
            Do While wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value = "59C"
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 8 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 9 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("B" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 10 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("C" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 11 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("D" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 12 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("E" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 13 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("F" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 14 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("G" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 15 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("H" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 16 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("I" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 17 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("J" & lSourceRow).Value

                lSourceRow = lSourceRow + 1
                lOffset = lOffset + 10
            Loop
            lSourceRow = lSourceRow - 1

        ElseIf wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value = "60C" Then
            lOffset = 0
            Do While wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value = "60C"
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 18 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 19 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("B" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 20 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("C" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 21 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("D" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 22 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("E" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 23 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("F" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, 24 + lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("G" & lSourceRow).Value

                lSourceRow = lSourceRow + 1
                lOffset = lOffset + 7
            Loop
            lSourceRow = lSourceRow - 1

        End If

        lSourceRow = lSourceRow + 1
        wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Activate
    Loop

End Sub
```

Here is another version that accounts for the fact that you say 59C and 60C may be repeating.  The only issue with this is that it will skew the output format a bit.

e.g. if there are sometimes multiple 59s
58 a 59 b
58 a 59 b 60 c
58 a 59 b **59 b 60c**
58 a 59 b 60 c

The 60s don't line up.

```
Private Sub CommandButton33_Click()

    Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lSourceRow As Long
    Dim lTargetRow As Long
    Dim lOffset As Long

    'Define the source and target sheets
    Set wsSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    lSourceRow = 1
    lTargetRow = 0

    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    wsSource.Activate
    'Loop through the rows
    Do While lSourceRow <= lastRow

        'Check if we have the beginning of a flow
        If wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value = "ZHV" Then
            wsTarget.Range("A" & lTargetRow + 1).Value = wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value
            wsTarget.Range("B" & lTargetRow + 1).Value = wsSource.Range("B" & lSourceRow).Value
        End If

        If wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value = "58C" Then

            lTargetRow = lTargetRow + 1
            lOffset = 8
            wsTarget.Range("C" & lTargetRow).Value = wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value
            wsTarget.Range("D" & lTargetRow).Value = wsSource.Range("B" & lSourceRow).Value
            wsTarget.Range("E" & lTargetRow).Value = wsSource.Range("C" & lSourceRow).Value
            wsTarget.Range("F" & lTargetRow).Value = wsSource.Range("D" & lSourceRow).Value
            wsTarget.Range("G" & lTargetRow).Value = wsSource.Range("E" & lSourceRow).Value

        ElseIf wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value = "59C" Then

            Do While wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value = "59C"
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 1).Value = wsSource.Range("B" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 2).Value = wsSource.Range("C" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 3).Value = wsSource.Range("D" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 4).Value = wsSource.Range("E" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 5).Value = wsSource.Range("F" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 6).Value = wsSource.Range("G" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 7).Value = wsSource.Range("H" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 8).Value = wsSource.Range("I" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 9).Value = wsSource.Range("J" & lSourceRow).Value

                lSourceRow = lSourceRow + 1
                lOffset = lOffset + 10
            Loop
            lSourceRow = lSourceRow - 1

        ElseIf wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value = "60C" Then
            Do While wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value = "60C"
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset).Value = wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 1).Value = wsSource.Range("B" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 2).Value = wsSource.Range("C" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 3).Value = wsSource.Range("D" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 4).Value = wsSource.Range("E" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 5).Value = wsSource.Range("F" & lSourceRow).Value
                wsTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lOffset + 6).Value = wsSource.Range("G" & lSourceRow).Value

                lSourceRow = lSourceRow + 1
                lOffset = lOffset + 7
            Loop
            lSourceRow = lSourceRow - 1

        End If

        lSourceRow = lSourceRow + 1
        wsSource.Range("A" & lSourceRow).Activate
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. Exactly what i'm looking for, with some minor tweaks I've added. Thanks @MatthewD !

Comment: Just to let you know I went with the second code because, although it may skew the data (not a problem), it actually keeps all the data being converted, unlike the hybrid of my own code (which I know wasn't very effective), which missed some parts out. Thanks again!!